# OpenCV OS X 10.12sierra

Tags: macos, opencv

```
  'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
JefferydeMacBook-Pro:build jefferyfan$ cd ~
JefferydeMacBook-Pro:~ jefferyfan$ brew install QTKit
Error: No available formula with the name "qtkit" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

This error shows up.
and Homebrew have problems as well.

Comment: What did you run to get this output? What is the question? Come on - try a bit harder if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

`brew install opencv3 --HEAD --with-contrib`

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

> In macOS 10.12, apple removed most of QTKit's components, include some functions and header files opencv use, so opencv 3 can't compile on macOS 10.12 (eg. header file "QTKit/QTKit.h" file has been removed, which is included in "cap_qtkit.mm").

[Source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6913)

Currently the only way to compile OpenCV on Sierra is to disable the modules using QTKit. Just add this flag when you run cmake to disable it.

```
cmake -DBUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF
```